# How two transition probability matrices can be used to find one variable in analysis

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, transition-matrix

I'm working on a research paper for cricket analysis but I'm stuck on the point of the estimation of $\tau_{owj}$, which is defined in the appendix. I have calculated up through $\alpha_{owj}$ and $\beta_{owj}$, but can't figure out $\tau_{owj}$ after that. The data is ball by ball data of T20 matches of all batsman.

[image: here is the info]

What I have understood is that $\alpha_{owj}$ is the transition probability matrix that represents the changes in states of overs and $\beta_{owj}$ represents when a change occurs in state of wickets. Hence we can calculate $\tau_{owj}$ based on changes in state of either of them, but how do I calculate $\tau_{owj}$ if both wickets and overs change at the same time?

This is the research paper: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/anzs.12109.

Comment: I don't think this is clear enough (a) without detail on the $\tau$ you want -- references are fine but no question should depend on anyone reading them -- and (b) without detail on what you don't understand. (Sadly, "I don't understand" is a statement, not a question.)

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.